# Revoke mysql permissions on database

Tags: mysql, permissions

Im trying to remove all permissions for a user on a database.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* FROM 'user'@'%';
```

This just gives an error saying:

```
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'user' on host '%'
```

I am logged in as root user when running the query. And running show grants for user query shows that the user has permissions on all databases

Output from show grants query:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxxxx'
```

Comment: can you include the output of `SHOW GRANTS for 'user'@'%'`>

Comment: @AlexTartan Added the output for show grants

Comment: `*.*` and `database.*` are two different things. Remove the grant for `*.*` and, if needed, add grants for the other databases

Comment: Am i correct to assume that `database.*` are all the tables of a specified database and `*.*` are all databases?

Comment: @A.Jac `database.*` means all tables from that database, and `*.*` means all tables from all databases on this server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revoke statement has to match the grants issued. If grant is issued to `*.*`, you can only revoke `*.*` as well.

since `SHOW GRANTS for 'user'@'%'` shows a line like:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxxxx'
```

You need to revoke *that*!

This should work:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'user'@'%';
```

`database.*` denotes all tables in the "database" database
`*.*` denotes all tables in all databases

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the below queries,

1) REVOKE ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE USER, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, DROP, EVENT, EXECUTE, FILE, INDEX, INSERT, LOCK TABLES, PROCESS, REFERENCES, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, SHOW VIEW, SHUTDOWN, SUPER, TRIGGER, UPDATE ON *.* FROM ‘user'@'%’;

OR

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM ‘user'@'%';

2) REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON *.* FROM ‘user'@'%';